# Adding raphael generated charts to the document with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, raphael

I am creating a bunch of charts with raphaeljs and I want to add them to the content of specific divs once the page is loaded.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="chartdiv">
    <span class="A">35</span>
    <div class="charthere"></div>
</div>

<div class="chartdiv">
    <span class="A">25</span>
    <div class="charthere"></div>
</div>

<div class="chartdiv">
    <span class="A">15</span>
    <div class="charthere"></div>
</div>
```

The following jQuery code should loop through all divs with the class chartdiv, and for each

- get the value in the span with the class A,
- pass it to the drawChart function
- put the svg in the div with the class charthere

Here the relevant part of my js script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div.chartdiv').each(function(){
        // get the A value
        var A = parseInt($(this).add('span.A').text());

        // substitute the html with the corresponding chart
        drawChart($(this).add('div.charthere'), A);
    });

    function drawChart(element, A) {
        var paper = new Raphael(element, 200, 200);
        var examplePathString = "M20,100 L" + A + ",100";
        var thePath = paper.path(examplePathString);
        thePath.attr({stroke: red,'stroke-width': 5px});
    }
});
```

What happens instead is that all the svg elements are created after the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

**1--** Using [jQuery's `.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) adds *anything* matching the selector to the selection, *in addition to* whatever's already in it.

So, each `.add('div.charthere')` adds every `div.charthere` to the selection (*not narrowed to* children of the `div.chartdiv`), *alongside* the `div.chartdiv`.

It looks like what you're trying to do is go from the `div.chartdiv` down into the one `div.charthere` in that `div`. For that, you want **`.find('div.charthere')`** (or, if it's *always* going to be just one step down, `.children('div.charthere')`).

**2--** You're passing a jQuery object representing a jQuery selection of divs to Raphael. Raphael expects either a DOM element (the div itself) or an ID string. Raphael isn't a jQuery plugin, so it doesn't know what to do with jQuery objects.

jQuery objects are like a modified array acting as a wrapper around the actual DOM elements, so you can get the dom element itself with `$someObj[0]` (so long as it's the first item you're interested in).

So, **`.find('div.charthere')[0]`** should do the job.

---

You need to make sure that what you pass to `Raphael();` is one DOM element or string. Add `console.log(element);` to the start of your function and look at the console in a debugger like Firebug and you'll probably see a lot more elements each time than you wanted.

(you also don't normally need the `new` in `new Raphael()` - [`var paper = Raphael()` is what is suggested in the official docs](http://raphaeljs.com/) - but I don't think that's the cause of the problem)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. By looking at the console.log, I was able to get the right values (and this only once) by following your advice and using .children('span.A').text() instead of .add('span.A').text(). I also removed the 'new' when instantiating the Raphael object.

Comment: Still with drawChart($(this).children('div.charthere'), A); it looks like, looking at the console, that the element passed is the (empty) content of the div and not the div itself.

Comment: That made me realise there's a second problem - see edit above

Comment: The second part was the last thing I missed, thank you! In between I used a nasty hack with consisted in prepending a div with an id made of the concatenation of charthere and the index, and then to pass it  document.getElementById as argument of the drawChart() function. Ugly but it worked in the "mean" time ;)